# Send Direct Message using Twitter API does not work

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, postman, twitter-oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to send Direct Message to a user who I follow and who follows me.

When I first tried to make a POSTMAN request as per the document [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) I was getting a HTTP 415 response, media type not supported. I looked up the Error code in their document and understood that this was happening because the `callback_url` needed to be whitelisted.

So I followed this guide to whitelist the `callback_url` and generate the `access_request` token , i.e `oauth_token` and `oauth_secret` [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens)

So, was : 
1. Get successfully `oauth/request_token` and got the Response: `&oauth_callback_confirmed=true` for the callback_url configured my app details. As far as I could tell, that's all I thought, I needed to do to whitelist the `callback_url`
2. Got `oauth_verifier` and final `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`

But, after generating the `outh_token` and `oauth_token_secret` and using it to make the DM API call, Now I am getting

> ```
> {
> "errors": [
>     {
>         "code": 32,
>         "message": "Could not authenticate you."
>     }
> ] }
> ```

When I try to make a GET auth/authenticate call as [documented here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/authenticate), I get a HTTP 403 with a message

> Whoa there!
>
> The request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been
>   used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or
>   application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a
>   mistake.

I can see in the Documentation that `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json`

> Requires authentication?  Yes (user context only)

I think I am missing something. Can anyone please help me point in the right direction as to what I need to be able to send DM to users successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error just now, I regenerated my API Key & Secret for the account and the Access Token & Secret for the application and then my POST request worked correctly.